# Is there any solution to deploy Istio in Kubernetes Cluster without Helm

Tags: kubernetes, istio

We do not want to use Helm in our kubernetes cluster, but would like to have Istio. For me it looks like Isto can be installed on kubernetes only with Helm.

I guess i can copy all helm charts and substitute the helm-variables to become a kubernetes ready yaml-files. But this is a lot of manual work i do not want to do (for all new versions also).

Any ideas, if there is already a solution for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you don't have Tiller in your cluster and you don't want to install it - you can use installation method without Tiller (using only client Helm binary) - https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/helm/#option-1-install-with-helm-via-helm-template

For example, to get full Istio YAML manifest you can do

```
helm template install/kubernetes/helm/istio-init --name istio-init --namespace istio-system > istio.yaml
```

If you want to upgrade - download newer release of Istio chart and do the same and apply rendered manifest to your cluster.

Answer (score 1):

Sure you can install [Istio](https://istio.io/) without Helm.

It's even in official Istio documentation [Quick Start Evaluation Install](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/install/kubernetes/).

> Follow this flow to quickly evaluate Istio in a Kubernetes cluster on any platform. This flow installs Istio’s built-in **demo**  [configuration profile](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/config-profiles/) using basic Kubernetes commands without needing to download or install [Helm](https://github.com/helm/helm).

Helm is just a recommendation for installing Istio, because it's easier.

There is also another way that will work only on [Google Cloud Platform](https://cloud.google.com/).

If you use [Kubernetes Engine](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/) and will go into `Create Cluster`, at the bottom you have `Availability, networking, security, and additional features` if you click it one of additional features is `Enable Istio (beta)`.

If you tick that box your Kubernetes Cluster will be deployed with Istio working.
[image: Enable Istio tick box]

Comment: you are right, but ist a demo: `To install Istio for production use, we recommend using the Helm Installation guide instead, which provides many more options for selecting and managing the Istio configuration. This permits customization of Istio to operator specific requirements.`

Comment: @KiteUp You are correct but demo is build with everything, which you can chcek on [Installation Configuration Profiles](https://istio.io/docs/setup/kubernetes/additional-setup/config-profiles/). It's always recommended to install everything youself because it gives you more power as you can choose components.